# Retrofit Multipart Escaping Values

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to post data and Multipart is escaping my values when they are sent.

I use this line

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v2/search_bounds")
void search_bounds(@Part("bounds") ArrayList<Bounds> bounds, @Part("filters") SearchCriteria searchCriteria, Callback<SearchResults> cb);
```

and when it's sent to the server the values look like this

```
bounds=>[{lat=/"-41.00049/", lng=/"45.8839/"}]
```

As you can see every quote is escaped. How do I send this post data without the quotes being escaped?

Comment: usually escaping stuff is done using \, not /